# How to find the sum of values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart in d3.js (version 6), where the x-axis is the infections and y-axis is the date. The csv file looks like this

```
code,country,date,cases
AFG,Afghanistan,2020-03-23,0.059,
US,United States,2020-03-24,0.063,
FR,France,2020-03-25,0.174,
GR,Germany,2020-03-26,0.195,
AFG,Afghanistan,2020-03-23,0.233,
US,United States,2020-03-24,0.285,
FR,France,2020-03-25,0.278,
GR,Germany,2020-03-26,0.257,
```

Now I want to get the total value for each date (so for 2020-03-2 the value should be 0.292, etc.) I read that d3.rollups would make this work but I am not sure I am using it right. This is what I have done so far:

```
const parseDate= d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

d3.csv("./multilinedata.csv").then(function(dataline) {
    dataline.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.cases= +d.cases
    });
    const totalCase = d3.rollups(dataline, g => g.sum, d=>d.date);
    console.log(totalCase);
```

This is the output I get

[image]

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your CSV is incorrect, drop those commas at the end of each row.

That said, the [`d3.rollup`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#rollup) method requires the data array, the reduce function itself and the keys. This is how it should be in your case:

```
const totalCase = d3.rollup(data, d => d3.sum(d, e => e.cases), d => d.date);
```

Here is the demo (because this is a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) look at your browser's console, not the SO snippet's one):

```js
const csv = `code,country,date,cases
AFG,Afghanistan,2020-03-23,0.059
US,United States,2020-03-24,0.063
FR,France,2020-03-25,0.174
GR,Germany,2020-03-26,0.195
AFG,Afghanistan,2020-03-23,0.233
US,United States,2020-03-24,0.285
FR,France,2020-03-25,0.278
GR,Germany,2020-03-26,0.257`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

const totalCase = d3.rollup(data, d => d3.sum(d, e => e.cases), d => d.date);

console.log(totalCase)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a methode of reduce can find the sum of values of array.

you can put your values in array and do this methode.

syntax:

```
yourArry.reduce((total, value) => total + value);
```

I hove your probleme was solved.